# How do you retrieve the file path from a checked list box that has multiple subfiles from different directories?

Tags: vb.net, checkedlistbox, directoryinfo

I've got a checked list box that populates files and subfiles from a selected location using a folder browser dialog. What I'm trying to accomplish is retrieve each location/directory of every checked item within that list. I'm using these locations as a spot to copy and paste new files into if that makes sense.

I should add that I'm new to coding, and I don't know how to do something as "complex" as this. This is also my first post and I apologize if this is an easier type question for you guys.

```
For Each file As IO.FileInfo In ListBox1.CheckedItems
    Dim NewFileName As String = FindListBox2ItemThatContains(file.Name)
    Dim lstfiles As String = Directory.GetFiles(FBD2.SelectedPath)
    If NewFileName.Trim.Length > 0 Then 
        IO.File.Copy(file.FullName, IO.Path.Combine(FBD2.SelectedPath, "item parent folder", NewFileName.Trim), True)
    End If
    ProgressBar1.Increment(+1) 
Next
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Dim lstFiles() As String = Directory.GetFiles("You Mapped drive: & "\", "*.xlsx")

Comment: doesn't that need to be in a loop so that it gets the correct file path on each loop?

Comment: For Each file As IO.FileInfo In ListBox1.CheckedItems

            Dim NewFileName As String = FindListBox2ItemThatContains(file.Name)
            Dim lstfiles As String = Directory.GetFiles(FBD2.SelectedPath)
            If NewFileName.Trim.Length > 0 Then IO.File.Copy(file.FullName, IO.Path.Combine(FBD2.SelectedPath, "item parent folder", NewFileName.Trim), True)
            ProgressBar1.Increment(+1)

        Next

Comment: the "IO.Path.Combine(FBD2.SelectedPath, "item parent folder", " is where i need the code for the file to be saved in, but i don't know how to reference it to get there.

Comment: Edit your question to include the new code (the `Edit` button is right below it). It is very hard to read code in the comments.

Comment: Also, please don't write the language in the title. Stack Overflow's tag system ensures that users and search engines find the posts they want. For more info see: [**Should questions include "tags" in their titles?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)